# Синтаксис C#. Как грамотно записать условие if чтобы выяснить, является ли значение переменной строковым?

Tags: c#, консоль, if, условия

Хочу проработать все возможные варианты входных данных от пользователя, но столкнулся с небольшой проблемой :[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Мне неизвестно, как проверить переменную на принадлежность к типу string (или вообще к какому нибудь типу), а гугл меня спасёт в лучшем случае когда-нибудь потом. Если я не решу эту проблему, то:

- Добавится ещё один "висяк" в мой список проблемных задач;
- Я сегодня буду плохо спать, думая о том, как я буду решать её завтра;
- Через три для галактика сломается.

Помогите пожалуйста.

P.S:Да, я знаю, что можно обработать верные варианты через switch-case или через if, а неверные учесть в else.

Comment: Typeof(choice) == Typeof(string)? А ещё лучше использовать int.tryparse

Comment: `if (choice is String){...}` но вообще вы 2 переменную `choice` создали как `int`, потому `String` в нем записан быть не может.

Comment: Вставлю свои 5 копеек. Лучше вставлять код не картинкой, а текстом, так читаемость лучше и можно код копировать :)

Comment: @AntonNikolaev спасибо, я учту!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Разделите проверки на несколько этапов.
Итак, вы считали введенный пользователем в консоль текст:

```
string printedChoice = Console.Readline();
```

Если вам нужна целочисленная интерпретация этого текста - попробуйте преобразовать его в число с помощью метода Int32.TryParse. Это и будет первым этапом проверки.

```
int choice = 0;
Int32.TryParse(printedChoice, out choice);
```

Если преобразование прошло успешно, переменная choice приобрела новое значение. Если нет - `choice` останется равным нулю. Теперь можно выполнить проверку значения на соответствие диапазону, не беспокоясь о типах.

```
if (choice < 2 && choice > 6) 
{
   //далее ваш код
}
else
{
   // пользователь ввёл чушь
}
```

Comment: `Если нет - choice останется равным нулю` - на это не стоит полагаться. Сам метод `Int32.TryParse(...)` возвращает bool, так что можно писать просто `if (Int32.TryParse(...)){...}else{...}`

Comment: `Если нет - choice останется равным нулю` стоит явно указать, то будет присвоено значение типа по-умолчанию `default(int)`, т.е. если до этой операции choice был не 0, то после нее при некорректной входной строке, будет 0.

Comment: Я намеренно не усложнял листинг для автора, поэтому не использовал  возвращаемое значение функции `TryParse`. Обратите внимание - он использует `goto`, и вложенный `if` может стать в этом случае проблемой.

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае нет нужды в проверке типов, потому что типы известны заранее:

1. [`Console.ReadLine`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.readline?view=netframework-4.8) - возвращается **всегда** `string`
2. [`Convert.ToInt32`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.toint32?view=netframework-4.8#System_Convert_ToInt32_System_String_) - возвращает **всегда** `int`

Таким образом у переменной `choice` тип `int`, и проверка на любой другой тип выдаст `false`.

Если будет ошибка при переводе из строки в число, будет выкинуто исключение, и до условия выполнение не дойдет.

Comment: может стоит упомянуть `TryParse` как вариант что делать, если введено не число?

Comment: @tym32167, да я думал об этом, но что-то решил только на типах ограничиться :)

Answer (score 0):

Почему бы не использовать регулярные вырождения в данном случаи ?

вот `^[1-6]{1}$` регулярное выражение которое позволит вводить одну цифру в диапазоне от 1 до 6 
ниже пример кода:

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      Console.WriteLine("Введите число от 1 до 6");
      var inputData =  Console.ReadLine();

      Regex checkRegex = new Regex("^[1-6]{1}$");

        if (checkRegex.IsMatch(inputData)) //условия соблюдены : введенно одно число в диапозоне от 1 до 6
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Успешный ввод");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Данные введены не вернно!!");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```